# Generate a random number for data-id in html

Tags: jquery, html

I want to generate a random data-id for every html that I need to save in the database, but I dont know how to properly implement it

```
 var html='<div class="portlet portlet-sortable light bordered ui-widget-content ui-resizable" style="display: block;" data-id:Generator()>'
```

js

```
function Generator(){};

Generator.prototype.rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + Date.now();

Generator.prototype.getId = function() {
return this.rand++;
```

full html

```
idGen = new Generator();
var $randomId = idGen.getId();
var html='<div class="portlet portlet-sortable light bordered ui-widget-content ui-resizable" style="display: block;" data-id="' + $randomId + '">'
+'<div class="portlet-title ui-sortable-handle">'
+'<div class="caption font-green-sharp">'
+'<i class="icon-speech font-green-sharp"></i>'
+'<span class="caption-subject bold uppercase"> '+$widgetTitle+'</span>'
+'</div>'
+'<div class="actions">'
+'<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-sm remove">'
+'<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove </a>'
+'<div class="btn-group">'
+'<a class="btn btn-circle btn-default " href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">'
+'<i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Settings'
+'<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>'
+'<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">'
+'<li>'
+'<a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a></li>'
+'<li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span class="delete"> Delete </span></a></li>'
+'<li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Ban </a></li>'
+'<li class="divider"> </li>'
+'<li><a href="javascript:;"> Make admin </a></li>'
+'</ul>'
+'</div>'
+'<a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default fullscreen" href="javascript:;"></a>'
+'</div>'
+'</div>'
+'<div class="portlet-body">'
+'<div>'+$widgetContent+'</div>'
+'</div>'
+'</div>';
 return html;
```

},

Comment: *"dont know how to  implement it"* is a very vague statement. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean how to use the function Generator inside div to create a random number in data-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to concatenate the value within the string parts:

```
var html='<div class="..." style="..."  data-id="' + Generator() +'">'
```

Or create jQuery object from the html string and do:

```
var $div = $(html).data('id', Generator());
$('#someOtherDiv').append($div)
```

Comment: just one more thing, how to get that data-id (example I need to delete it)

Comment: can use jQuery `data('id')` as getter

Comment: this is my script  $(".remove").click(function() {
        var data_id = $('div.portlet').attr('data-id');
        alert(data_id);  but this alert undefined

Comment: what does `alert($('div.portlet').length)` show? Are you sure generator is returning a value? have you tried it by itself? Inspect the live html in browser dev tools and see what is being set in `data-id`

Comment: Seems like you want `Generator.getId()`

Comment: it returns 3, and I have three divs with same class, I want to get the data-id for a specific div.When I tried to alert, all divs alerts same number, but I can see they save different data-id's in view source code

Comment: ok...well need more detail about how layout works. Is there a `remove` for each portlet? If so what is layout relationship

Comment: Bit hard to see tree without indents but looks like it is inside so just do `var data_id = $(this).closest('div.portlet').attr('data-id');`

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript - DOM manipulation on data-number using setAttribute

```js
let getRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
let myRandom = document.getElementById("my-random");
  myRandom.setAttribute("data-number", getRandomNumber )
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

.ball {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 40%, #fcfcfc, #efeff1 66%, #9b5050 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: ballGrow 2s ease-out forwards;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
.ball:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 14%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 24%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
  transform: translateX(-80px) translateY(-90px) skewX(-20deg);
}

.stage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -ms-perspective: 1200px;
  -o-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 160px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  animation: ballRoll 2s ease-out;
}

.number:after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-75%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: numberReveal 0.1s 1.5s reverse forwards;
}

.number:before {
  content: '?';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  animation: numberReveal 0.1s 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes ballRoll {
  0%, 20%, 50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0) scale(1);
  }
  10%, 35%, 75% {
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(170deg) scale(0.4);
  }
  11%, 36%, 76% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(-170deg) scale(0.3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
}

@keyframes ballGrow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes numberReveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


.stage:nth-child(2) .ball,
.stage:nth-child(2) .number {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.stage:nth-child(2) .number:after,
.stage:nth-child(2) .number:before {
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

.stage:nth-child(3) .ball,
.stage:nth-child(3) .number {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.stage:nth-child(3) .number:after,
.stage:nth-child(3) .number:before {
  animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

.stage:nth-child(4) .ball,
.stage:nth-child(4) .number {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.stage:nth-child(4) .number:after,
.stage:nth-child(4) .number:before {
  animation-delay: 2.4s;
}
```

```html
  <section class="stage">
        <figure class="ball">
          <span class="number" id="my-random" data-number="?">&nbsp;</span>
        </figure>
  </section>
```